# How to register a home custom route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a web site without custom routes, just the default route. 
I needed to create a GET action for a thirdy customer, so the custumer will need the url and pass a speciefic parameter to my Action. But I would Like to provide the simpliest url as possible. 
For example:

**http://mycustomsite.com/idParameter**

My default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }         // Parameter defaults
        );
```

I tried this one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "CustomRoute",
            "{idParameter}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "CustomAction", idParameter= UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But it not works. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Keep in mind that order matters in defining route. Try put your custom route above the default one.

Comment: @WeTTTT thanks for your response, but, if i put it above, the action will execute and for default i dont have any parameters in the url. So, if i just execute the http://mycustomsite.com/ it throws an error saying that i need to pass some parameter.

Comment: In your action you can either give a default value to the parameter like `public ActionResult ActionName(int id = 0)`, or make it nullable like `public ActionResult ActionName(int? id)`